# Facing problems with Play2.x and the new newRelic javaagent

Tags: scala, playframework, netty, playframework-2.1, newrelic

Tried the newrelic javaagent for Play2.x with versions 2.1.1 and 2.1.2 with scala

When I deploy my application with the newrelic javaagent my app gradually slows down and becomes unresponsive after a minute or so.

That happens only on production mode (when the app constantly receives requests 30-100 reqs/s).

Anyone else faced this problem?
Any solution?

Tried it with newrelic 2.19 and 2.20 for java but no luck.

Here is my akka config (if that matters)

```
akka {
 actor {
    ws-dispatcher {
        type = "Dispatcher"
         fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-factor = 2.0
            parallelism-max = 100
         }
    }
    webservice-context{
        type = "Dispatcher"
        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-factor =2.0
            parallelism-min = 16
            parallelism-max = 16
        }
    }
    db-context{
        type = "Dispatcher"
        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-factor =1.0
            parallelism-min=1
            parallelism-max=1
        }
    }

    redis-context{
        type = "Dispatcher"
        fork-join-executor {
            parallelism-factor = 1.0
            parallelism-min = 4
            parallelism-max = 4
        }
    }

}
```

Update

Added that to newrelic.yml as @Tyler suggested but still the same problem

```
class_transformer:
  akka_instrumentation:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: We (at New Relic) haven't seen this error before. We'd really like you to open a support ticket with us so we could take a look at some detailed logs. Please get in touch with us at support@newrelic.com

Comment: @Toby_New_Relic I did and the support was *really* great. Sadly the problem could not get reproduced so I'm asking the community

Comment: How is your memory usage affected?

Comment: Memory is fine. When the problem appears (nothing serving) 1 out of 4 CPU's is 100% all the time.

Comment: try adding this (with the appropriate indentation) to your yml file to disable the akka instrumentation:
      class_transformer:
        akka_instrumentation:
          enabled: false

Comment: Thank you @Tyler. Updated the answer. I added it to the end of my newrelic.yml with 2 spaces indentation for each level. Still huge performance issues. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @weakwire, Are you using OpenJDK or OracleJDK?  Also, just to clarify, the problem is only presented when New Relic is enabled, right?

Comment: @Tyler It's OracleJDK on a 64 bit VM. Yes only when NewRelic is enabled and only when there is high traffic. For eg I enable new Relic  with no traffic. Everything goes as expected for a long time. I target the load balancer to the server. Everything stars to slow down and become unrensponsive. Then when I switch off the load balancer everything is normal again. Is only happens under presure.

Comment: It sounds to me like some hot path got instrumented. May need to do a thread profile or check the logs for more clarification. Do you have any custom instrumentation that you've added?

Answer (score 3):

New Relic's Java Agent has been significantly refactored in version 3, with big changes in how it instruments Play apps. This issue can probably be solved by an agent upgrade.